# WordPress hide errors in log when duplicate key found

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I've this `$wpdb` insert here into my table. The only column in this table is a unique one so when the value already exists the SQL should not work which is planned this way. Now I've the problem that my logs are completely full with `Duplicate entry` errors. I've tried to disable the error logging like you can see but it's not working. Whats wrong?

```
$wpdb->insert( 'test', array(
    'test_column' => $test,
) );

//Hide wpdb errors if duplicate entry found
$wpdb->hide_errors();
```

Comment: Don't hide the problem, fix it. Test if the value exists before insert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @EquaPro said, hiding the error won't fix the issue: you're trying to insert a unique value that's already in the table.

Instead, you could check if the value exists before inserting it:

```
if ( ! $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare('SELECT test_column FROM table WHERE test_column = %s', $test) ) ) {
    $wpdb->insert( 'test', array(
        'test_column' => $test,
    ) );
}
```

... or you could do an `INSERT IGNORE` query and save yourself one query:

```
$wpdb->query(
    $wpdb->prepare('INSERT IGNORE INTO table (test_column) VALUES (%s)', $test)
);
```